# How to text align right with datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table id="table-DataView-Ceft-History" class="table table-bordered v-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:auto;">Date</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">MBSL Account No</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Reference No</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Amount(LKR)</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Reason</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Third Party Acc No</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Transfer status</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Target Bank</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Transfer By</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ***jQuery***, it can be done by `css` method

```
$('#table-DataView-Ceft-History thead th').css('text-align', 'right');
```

***OR,*** we can use `text-align: right;` css property for right alignment of text in `th` tags

```css
th {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-DataView-Ceft-History" class="table table-bordered v-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:auto;">Date</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">MBSL Account No</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Reference No</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Amount(LKR)</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Reason</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Third Party Acc No</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Transfer status</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Target Bank</th>
      <th style="width:auto;">Transfer By</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```